# Isochronous iMX6 USB gadget Implementation Issue

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, imx6

I'm trying to implement a USB gadget using Linux on NXP iMX6 which implements an isochronous IN endpoint but got stuck as the gadget application on the iMX6 seems to hang, and eventually resulting a reboot of my i.MX6 platform.

Started with the usb.c example from http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/usb.c and modifying it for the iMX6.

The Linux Kernel used for this development is Ver. 4.1.15.

Then, mounting the gadgetfs framework using:
modprobe gadgetfs
mkdir /dev/gadget
mount -t gadgetfs none /dev/gadget

This results in a 2184000.usb file in the /dev/gadget directory.

Modified the usb.c example to look for this 2184000.usb file and fill a set of USB descriptors. The host computer did recognizing the iMX6 as a USB device with the USB descriptors which I configured. But then, the gadget application on the i.MX6 seems to just hang and then reboot my Linux platform eventually.

Has anyone experience the same situation and got a solution? Please can you share source code or suggestion? Thanks!